# Disable ToggleButtons that were added by DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MainWindow.xaml, that has a resizable buttongrid. The size and content of said ButtonGrid is bound to a list of `LFields`, which is a custom class. So I have some fields set up in my ViewModel:

```
int num = 1;

public void SetupGame() {
    _Fields = new ObservableCollection<LField>();
    int num = 1;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < _model.Numbers / 5; i++) 
    {
        for (Int32 j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Fields.Add(new LField
            {
                Text = num.ToString(),
                X = i,
                Y = j,
                IsChecked = false,
                Number = num,
                ButtonChecker = new DelegateCommand(
                    param => CheckButton(Convert.ToInt32(param)))
            });
            num++;
        }
    }
    OnPropertyChanged("Fields");
}
```

And then, based on these `LFields`, I create a grid of buttons in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ButtonGrid" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Rows}" Columns="{Binding Columns}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ToggleButton Command="{Binding ButtonChecker}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Number}"
                    Content="{Binding Text}"
                    Focusable="False"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                    BorderThickness="0.3"
                    BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>

  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding X}" />
      <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Y}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, at some point, I want to disable all of these buttons in my ViewModel. But, since they're created by a template, I can't just do `buttonname.IsEnabled = false;`. So how can I disable all these buttons in my ViewModel? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I've bound the `ToggleButton`'s `IsEnabled` property to a property in `LField`. Then I iterate over `Fields` to set it when I want to disable the button, however, the buttons don't get disabled. If I change the text, that works, but the buttons all stay enabled. So this:

```
foreach (LField field in Fields)
{
    field.IsEnabled = false;
    field.Text = "test";
}
```

does change the text, but doesn't disable the buttons.

Comment: Bind the ToggleButton's `IsEnabled` property to another property in `LField`. Then iterate over `Fields` to set this property.

Comment: Oh cool, that worked! Thank you!

Comment: Or at least it works when I use it at creation, however, when I iterate over to update it, it doesn't disable the buttons, even though I use `OnPropertyChanged`, too.

Comment: The fields do get `IsEnabled = false`, but the buttons are still clickable.

Comment: @Andy Yes and yes. As I just added, the Text does get updated, only the buttons are not disabled.

Comment: You certainly made something wrong when calling OnPropertyChanged. Check the property name.

Comment: I didn't really. I've double and triple checked...

Comment: @Clemens If you have the time, could you please check? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxO12vzqdjgNRmdqaFg5ZllHZW8 Here's the code. I'm setting the property in LViewModel.cs line 74.

Comment: Sorry, I won't download anything.

Comment: @Clemens I'm in uni, not as if I could write a virus even if I wanted to :D Will you check if I put it on codeshare?

Comment: Sorry, not at all.

Comment: @Clemens So it's really not about downloading stuff, it's just that you're not keen on helping?

Comment: Quite the opposite, which you might have noticed by looking at my reputation. But you have to show your code here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Clemens You really expect me to put 500 lines of code up here? :D It'd be so much easier to just launch the .sln and check it... But okay. I guess I'll just have to wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: @Clemens Btw I think all the relevant code is in the post. What else might you need to see?

Comment: See here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For the "relevant parts", you've neither shown the implementation of the IsEnabled property in class LField, nor how the Binding to it looks like.